# IndexPathForRowAtPoint Not Working iOS 13.4.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer, ios13.4

I have a TableView populated with UITableViewHeaders (sections) ... There is a LongGesture on the Header and I use code below to drag header for re-ordering. Now this works on all my devices up to 13.3.1 but just recently was getting complaints from users that the tableview was not responsive. Below is the code used in short to grab index of current view held which works until iOS 13.4.1, Any suggestions/work arounds would be greatly appreciated

```
- (void)longPressGestureRecognized:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)longPress {

UIGestureRecognizerState state = longPress.state;    
CGPoint location = [longPress locationInView:self.mainTable];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.mainTable indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];


//do my cool stuff  with index path....

}
```

Comment: I'm having same issue on iOS 13.5.1
Did you find any solution @ FreeAppl3?